# hacked/malfunction base system. resources to flash stock firmware on Motorola

Tags: device-firmware

After visiting some shady sites like tpb and clicking a link  my phone just reset on it's own and now my keyboard reset to default, I can't access the notifications dropdown, or use the return to desktop button.

I've read that it shouldn't be too big of a hassle to reflash it, which I am assuming would get rid of well-buried rootkits.

Is an official pure-android image available for Motorola phones still currently in retail? What's the best resource for doing this through linux adb?

Comment: Motorola does a bad job at making these resources officially available... Best bet is to go to the device-specific subforum on XDA-Developers.

Comment: What device specifically, model and variant (country, carrier, etc)? A good answer would be`Moto X Pure Edition XT1575 Retail US on build MPHS24.49-18-16` ... Most retail Moto devices have leaked firmware out there that is flashed with fastboot, but not all, and Moto is less than forthcoming to provide firmware image for most devices that are not sold as Developer units.